#  Unable to create a constant value of type. Only use primitive types 

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4

I've read some other posts but they have not helped.

CarPart is an EF4 gened class

```
[EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="xxxx.Data.Domain.Model", Name="CarPart")]
[Serializable()]
[DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
public partial class CarPart : EntityObject
{
    #region Factory Method

    /// summary>
    /// Create a new CarPart object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="carPartId">Initial value of the CarPartId property.</param>
    /// <param name="name">Initial value of the Name property.</param>
    /// <param name="carPartTypeId">Initial value of the CarPartId property.</param>
    public static CarPart CreateCarPart(global::System.Int32 carPartId, global::System.String name, global::System.Int32 carPartId)
    {
        CarPart carPart = new CarPart();
        carPart.CarPartId = carPartId;
        carPart.Name = name;
        carPart.CarPartTypeId = carPartTypeId;
        return carPart;
    }

    #endregion
    #region Primitive Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=true, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.Int32 CarPartId
    {
        get
        {
            return _CarPartId;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_CarPartId != value)
            {
                OnCarPartIdChanging(value);
                ReportPropertyChanging("CarPartId");
                _CarPartId = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
                ReportPropertyChanged("CarPartIdId");
                OnCarPartIdChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    private global::System.Int32 _CarPartId;
    partial void OnCarPartIdChanging(global::System.Int32 value);
    partial void OnCarPartIdChanged();

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.String Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _Name;
        }
        set
        {
            OnNameChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("Name");
            _Name = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, false);
            ReportPropertyChanged("Name");
            OnNameChanged();
        }
    }
    private global::System.String _Name;
    partial void OnNameChanging(global::System.String value);
    partial void OnNameChanged();

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.Int32 CarPartTypeId
    {
        get
        {
            return _CarPartTypeId;
        }
        set
        {
            OnCarPartTypeIdChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("CarPartTypeId");
            _CarPartTypeId = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
            ReportPropertyChanged("CarPartTypeId");
            OnCarPartTypeIdChanged();
        }
    }
    private global::System.Int32 _CarPartTypeId;
    partial void OnCarPartTypeIdChanging(global::System.Int32 value);
    partial void OnCarPartTypeIdChanged();

    #endregion

    #region Navigation Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    [SoapIgnoreAttribute()]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    [EdmRelationshipNavigationPropertyAttribute("xxxx.Data.Domain.Model", "FK_CarPartId", "Part")]
    public EntityCollection<Part> Parts
    {
        get
        {
            return ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedCollection<Part>("xxxxx.Data.Domain.Model.FK_CarPartId", "Part");
        }
        set
        {
            if ((value != null))
            {
                ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.InitializeRelatedCollection<Part>("xxxx.Data.Domain.Model.FK_CarPartId", "Part", value);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    [SoapIgnoreAttribute()]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    [EdmRelationshipNavigationPropertyAttribute("xxxxx.Data.Domain.Model", "FK_CarPartTypeId", "CarPartType")]
    public CarPartType CarPartType
    {
        get
        {
            return ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedReference<CarPartType>("xxxx.Data.Domain.Model.FK_CarPartTypeId", "CarPartType").Value;
        }
        set
        {
            ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedReference<CarPartType>("xxxxx.Data.Domain.Model.FK_CarPartTypeId", "CarPartType").Value = value;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [BrowsableAttribute(false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public EntityReference<CarPartType> CarPartTypeReference
    {
        get
        {
            return ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedReference<CarPartType>("xxxx.Data.Domain.Model.FK_CarPartTypeId", "CarPartType");
        }
        set
        {
            if ((value != null))
            {
                ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.InitializeRelatedReference<CarPartType>("xxxxxx.Data.Domain.Model.FK_CarPartTypeId", "CarPartType", value);
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

So here's my join code:

```
List<Parts> parts = _context.Parts.Where(p => p.PartId == partId).ToList();

List<CarParts> parts = _context.CarParts
     .Join(parts, cp => cp.PartId, p => p.PartId, (cp, p) => cp).ToList();
```

> Error: Unable to create a constant value of type 'Model.CarParts'. Only
>   primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in
>   this context.

Tried to look at it but can't get past this.  I'm a bit new to LINQ-To-SQL..done a fair amount but not a ton (mostly done LINQ to Objects) so new to joins with this.

Comment: I don't know what a *DL class* is. Can you post the code for `Model.Token`?

Comment: Data Layer.  The makup is just an EF4 (Entity Framework) gened type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i'm understanding right you want to do something like this:

```
internal class Db
{
    public Db()
    {
        var parts = new List<Part>
                        {
                            new Part() {PartId = 1, PartName = "Part 1"},
                            new Part() {PartId = 2, PartName = "Part 2"},
                        };
        Parts = parts.AsQueryable();
        var carParts = new List<CarPart>
                           {
                               new CarPart() {CarPartId = 1, CarPartName = "Car Part 1.1", PartId = 1},
                               new CarPart() {CarPartId = 1, CarPartName = "Car Part 1.2", PartId = 1},
                               new CarPart() {CarPartId = 1, CarPartName = "Car Part 2.1", PartId = 2},
                           };
        CarParts = carParts.AsQueryable();
    }

    public IQueryable<Part> Parts { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<CarPart> CarParts { get; set; }
}

internal class CarPart
{
    public int CarPartId { get; set; }
    public string CarPartName { get; set; }
    public int PartId { get; set; }
}

internal class Part
{
    public int PartId { get; set; }
    public string PartName { get; set; }
}

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Db db = new Db();

        var result = from carPart in db.CarParts
                     join part in db.Parts on carPart.PartId equals part.PartId
                     select new {Part = part, CarPart = carPart};

        var lambdaResult = db.CarParts.Join(db.Parts, part => part.PartId, caPart => caPart.PartId,
                                            (carPart, part) => new {CarPart = carPart, Part = part});

        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Part.PartName);
            Console.WriteLine(item.CarPart.CarPartName);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("------------");
        foreach (var item in lambdaResult)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Part.PartName);
            Console.WriteLine(item.CarPart.CarPartName);
        }
}
```

the result is a new anonymous object with the joined objects as content.
it would print this to the console:

```
Part 1
Car Part 1.1
Part 1
Car Part 1.2
Part 2
Car Part 2.1
-------    
Part 1
Car Part 1.1
Part 1
Car Part 1.2
Part 2
Car Part 2.1
```

Comment: close I want CarParts joined by PartId to Parts..so all CarParts reltaed to a specific PartId (yea it's backwards but this is just an example)

Comment: so I have to use the from syntax?  I try to stay away from that as it's clutter to me...I like the lambda syntax better

Comment: you can just transform that to lambda if you want. for me its more like an sql query and i can get the contents of the statement better. your choice ;)

Comment: well I mean that's kinda what i had in the first place just a different way to use the lambda but let me try yours

Comment: if added a lambda example. better? :)

Comment: Yea I'm trying to think how to convert yours to a lambda expression...more trying to figure out how the later end of the expression will look like for specifying what you want from the join back.  Also looking at my LINQ in Action book :).

Comment: of course join examples in that book are query expressions, not lamdas darn.

Comment: thanks a lot, this helps learned a lot on the lambda for this one.